# I'm invoke a Sql Stored procedure through getSingleResult from a "for", but results gets be the same to each row

Tags: java, spring

I have this code in controller

```
@PostMapping(value="/Servicios/fetch-data/info-adicional", produces= {"application/json"})
public dto_encabezado getAddInfoItem(@RequestBody dto_encabezado encabezado) 
{
    encabezado.setValid(true);
    PA_ITEMS_INFO_ENTITY info;
    for(dto_detalle item: encabezado.getDetalle()) {
         info = new PA_ITEMS_INFO_ENTITY();

        try {
            info = FetchData.getAddInfoItem(item.getProducto(), 
                                            item.getProveedor() == null ? "" : item.getProveedor(),
                                            encabezado.isServicioArticulo() ? "S" : "I");

            item.setDescripcion(info.getDescription());//Nombre

        }catch(Exception e) {
            item.setComentario(e.getMessage());
            encabezado.setValid(false);
        }
    }
    return encabezado;
}
```

I implement stored procedure like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public PA_ITEMS_INFO_ENTITY getAddInfoItem(String itemCode, String cardCode, String docType) {
    StoredProcedureQuery sp = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getAddInfoItem");
    sp.setParameter("ItemCode", itemCode);
    sp.setParameter("CardCode", cardCode);
    sp.setParameter("DocType", docType);
    PA_ITEMS_INFO_ENTITY obj = new PA_ITEMS_INFO_ENTITY();
    obj = (PA_ITEMS_INFO_ENTITY)sp.getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(itemCode); //Print given parameter
    System.out.println(obj.getCode());//Code property is the same value of paramenter but was get as result into StoredProcedure 
    return obj;
}
```

property in Stored Procedure class

```
@Column(name = "ItemCode")
public String code;
```

There are no erros, but in console print this, seems the result code is repeated in stored procedure but the parameter is different. why?

- FL1341101-L //parameter
- FL1341101-L //result (ok)
- FL1341102-L //parameter
- FL1341101-L //result (bad, previous result)
- FL1320221-L //parameter
- FL1341101-L //result (bad, previous result)
- FL1331002-L //parameter
- FL1331002-L //result(ok)
- FL1341101-L //parameter
- FL1331002-L //result (bad, preious result)....
- FL1341102-L
- FL1331002-L
- FL1320221-L
- FL1331002-L

If I delete @Transaction anotation, the result is repeated for all rows..

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Close session if any is active, before to invoke getSingleResult() method...

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
if(session != null) {
    session.clear();
}
```

I hope you find it useful